# Mod RewriteRule not working on all URL's

Tags: mod-rewrite

this is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^(.*)wp-content/uploads/(.*) $1watermark.php?src=wp-content/uploads/$2

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

this line is my issue

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)wp-content/uploads/(.*) $1watermark.php?src=wp-content/uploads/$2
```

---

all my images are in subfolders within wp-content/uploads. an example of http://darrenkynochphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/darrenprofile.jpg does what it should and redirects the image through a watermark script.

But this example http://darrenkynochphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/23-2-950x635.jpg doesnt work at all, along with any other images. I cant see where i am going wrong here at all as it should work

Answer (score 1):

> The `RewriteEngine` directive enables or
>   disables the runtime rewriting engine.
>   If it is set to off this module does
>   no runtime processing at all.
>
> ...
>
> Default: `RewriteEngine off`

[Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteEngine)

If you have directives which appear before a `RewriteEngine on` directive, they will be ignored.

Comment: Simple solutions are always the best